# What if I alter my MAC address to my gateway's MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

Can I listen anyone in the same network? I've tried, but it doesn't work(if I've done it right).I can't see something valuable in wireshark on my laptop.

Comment: Are you trying to do man in the middle attack (ARP poisoning)?
What command did you use to change the Mac address ?